# How to obtain the last used row number of an Excel file using the ImportExcel Module

Tags: powershell

I'm very new to PowerShell and I'm trying to retrieve data from an Excel file using PowerShell on a server that does not have Microsoft Excel installed. Through some online digging, it looks like using the ImportExcel Module is my best bet: https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/ImportExcel/7.1.1

The excel file contains a header row and a list of transactions, where each row contains one transaction. Essentially, I am trying to obtain a count of the number of transactions in the file, which would be the total number of rows containing data minus one (for the header).

Through some online digging, I found the below code that will produce the value that I need. The only problem is that this completely relies on the Excel.Application object which does not exist (since Excel is not installed on the server). Is there an equivalent code where I can obtain the value of transactions that I need using the ImportExcel module? Let me know if I'm also thinking about this in a completely wrong way. Many thanks.

```
$xl = New-Object -COM "Excel.Application"
$xl.Visible = $true
$wb = $xl.Workbooks.Open("C:\path\to\the.xlsx")
$ws = $wb.Sheets.Item(1)
$rows = $ws.UsedRange.Rows.Count - 1
Write-Host "Trade Count:" $rows
$wb.Close()
$xl.Quit()
```

Comment: Open a workbook, start the macro recorder, do the steps you need, stop the macro recorder, copy the VBA code, use the VBA code from PowerShell.

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is indeed to use the module [ImportExcel](https://github.com/dfinke/ImportExcel). It uses the EPPLUS library so you don't have to use any COM-objects or install Excel on a server.

One way of counting the total rows, without counting the header row, would be to simply import the Excel file. When a standard import is done the first row is always used as a header row. The header row is not counted as an object in itself but only used for property names.

First you need to install the module from the PowerShell Gallery:

```
Install-Module ImportExcel
```

Then you can use it in your scripts:

```
# myScript.ps1
#Requires -Module ImportExcel

Param (
    $Path = 'C:\path\to\the.xlsx'
)

# the first row is used to create the property names
$importedExcelRows = Import-Excel -Path $Path
"Imported '$($importedExcelRows.Count)' rows from Excel file '$Path'"

# the '-NoHeader' switch also counts the first row
$importedExcelRows = Import-Excel -Path $Path -NoHeader
"Imported '$($importedExcelRows.Count -1)' rows from Excel file '$Path'"
```

Some helpful commands to get you started?

```
Get-Help Import-Excel # displays what a function does, its parameters, ..
Get-Help Import-Excel -Examples # displays how to use the function
Get-Command -Module ImportExcel # list all available functions in a module
```

Comment: Amazing. I will try this out and report back. Thank you for your guidance.

Comment: You're welcome. If this solves your issue don't forget to mark it as solved.

Comment: Yes, will do. I think it may take IT a week or two to install the ImportExcel module on the server.